# java - Deploy GAE app using a service account

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I need to deploy a java app to GAE using a service account.

For appcfg.py there is an option "--authenticate_service_account" that uses the GCE instance default service account. But this option is not available for appcfg.sh.

I would need to be able to somehow use appcfg.py to deploy a java app, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gcloud to deploy your app and it supports service accounts.  You can download gcloud here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Then, you want to download a new .json key file for your project from https://console.developers.google.com

Then authenticate with it:
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account  ACCOUNT --key-file KEY_FILE

Then you should be able to deploy:
$ gcloud preview app deploy

This is still in preview (which is why it is under the preview group).  Make sure you run:
$ gcloud components update app
to install the app component before you try to deploy.

Comment: I have activated the service account but when I try to deploy the app it is openning the browser for me to log in. Do I need to add any flag to the deploy call?

Comment: Found my error, I was registering the service account with the not. But I need to register it with the email.